# extraction of file from filepath

Tags: python

I need to extract file name without extension name.

example.

/home/si/text.txt

/home/si/text.vx.txt

In the both case I should receive output text only. I am not sure how many trailing extension file can have but I need to extract only file name. I have tried spliitext(filename)[0] but it gave me output text.vx rather than text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your needs:

```
from os.path import basename
print basename("/home/si/text.vx.txt").split('.')[0]
>>> text
```

Answer (score 0):

I use split function after getting file name.

filename.split('.')[0]